# Does the element of Galois Group always send roots to roots, even when the extension is not Galois?

Tags: galois-theory

Does the element of Galois Group always send roots to roots, even when the Galois extension is not Galois?

I learned that Gal$(E/F)$ always send the roots to the roots when the extension $E/F$ is Galois. However, how about the cases that $E/F$ is not Galois?

I thought about an example.
For example, $F=\Bbb Q$, $E=\Bbb Q(2^{1/4})$, $D=\Bbb Q(2^{1/4},i)$,
$f(x) = x^4-2 \in F[x]$, and $D/F$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$.

What will Gal$(E/F)$ be? 
$\text{id} \in \text{Gal}( E/F)$,
$\sigma\in\text{Gal}(E/F)$ where $\sigma: 2^{1/4}\mapsto -2^{1/4}$

but does, $\pi: 2^{1/4}\mapsto 2^{3/4}$ or $\pi: 2^{1/4}\mapsto - 2^{3/4} \in \text{Gal}(E/F)$ 
because $1$, $2^{1/4}$, $2^{1/2}$, $2^{3/4}$ are the vectors of $E$ over $F$.

My guess is that $\pi$ does not belong to $\text{Gal}(E/F)$ because $\pi: E \to E$ is not surjective since $\pi^{-1} (2^{1/4})$ , the preimage of $2^{1/4}$ under $\pi$ does not belong to $E$.

This is a very specific case that I tried. I would like to know about the more general answer.

Comment: I’m guessing that by the “Galois group” of a non-Galois extension $E\supset F$ you mean the set of all $F$-automorphisms of $E$. This set is a group, of order $n'$ strictly less than $n=[E:F]$. It may well happen that $n'=1$, for instance, but in your case I think that in addition to the identity, there’s the automorphism that sends $\sqrt[4]2$ to $-\sqrt[4]2$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Right, the Gal E/F here refers to the group of Automorphisms from E to E and fix F. I am not sure if it is strictly less than [E:F] because I thought about this question too I recalling extension theorem, but in my example, and similar ones, f doesn't split in E.

Comment: If you have a situation where $n'=n$, then in fact the extension was Galois.

Comment: thank you! I will think about this more carefully!

Comment: Normally we only call the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ a *Galois* group in the special case that $E/F$ is Galois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such automorphism $\pi$. Write $a=2^{1/4}$. Then $a^4=2$.
If $\pi$ is a field automorphism then $\pi(a)^4=\pi(a^4)=2$. So
$\pi(a)$ cannot equal $2^{3/4}$ since $(2^{3/4})=8\ne2$.

In general if $a$ is a root of the rational equation $f(x)=0$, then each automorphism will take $a$ to some root of $f(x)=0$. In this example $f(x)=x^4-2$, so the possible values of $\sigma(2^{1/4})$ are
$2^{1/4}$, $i2^{1/4}$, $-2^{1/4}$, $-i2^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like to ask one more question. I wonder in the case I asked about,  σ(2^1/4) can only be taken to 2^1/4 or -2^1/4 by the root-permutation nature of Gal E/F right? because these are the only two roots of f(x) in E.

Comment: @HDCY That is correct. As also explained in Lubin's comment, you do have an automorphism such that $\sigma(2^{1/4})=-2^{1/4}$.

Comment: As $E/F$ is not Galois, I'd write Aut$(E/F)$ rather than Gal$(E/F)$ to remind me that the extension isn't Galois. But yes, the automorphism of $D$ taking $2^{1/4}$ to $-2^{1/4}$ and $i$ to $i$ restricts to an automorphism of $E$.